# Is there any equivalent method in python for pcl_ros::transformPointCloud() and if not, how to efficiently implement it?

Tags: pcl, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with the python-pcl library, and there isn't any equivalent function to transform a point cloud from one frame to another and output in the format of PointCloud2.

Are there any alternatives to this in python/rospy? Or I will have to implement one myself?

I was considering using the lookupTransform() from Tf and obtaining the translation and rotation values and creating the transformation myself somehow. Not sure if it will be an efficient way to do so or not.

Surprised that there isn't much work for PCL+ROS in Python even now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264632/is-there-any-equivalent-method-in-python-for-pcl_ros::transformpointcloud()-and-if-not,-how-to-efficiently-implement-it?/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2017-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some python bindings for pointcloud manipulation in the sensor_msgs package, and also some bindings for tf2 in tf2_py, but nothing written that would use both for transforming pointclouds.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2017-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0